# SpringBoot Cucumber - It appears there was a problem with the step definition. The converted arguments types were ()

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, cucumber

Im newbie, im starting learnig springboot with cucumber and gradle and im facing this issue can someone resolve this issue

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots *and* include the full error message.